# Return a multiple value dictionary within a function into a pretty format

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.6, multiple-value

So the first 2 steps I took to come to this point were as follows:

1. I opened a textfile. The print-method provided me with this:

   ```
   ["string1","a","b","c"] 
   ["string2","d","e","f"]
   ["string3","g","h","i"] 
   ["string4","j","k","l"]
   ```
2. I converted these lists into a dictionary. It looks like this now:

   ```
   dictionary = {"string1":["a","b","c"], "string2":["d","e","f"],
                 "string3":["g","h","i"], "string4":["j","k","l"]}
   ```

My goal was to return this dictionary within a function, so that it looks like this when it's printed in a main function:

```
{
"string1":["a","b","c"],
"string2":["d","e","f"],
"string3":["g","h","i"],
"string4":["j","k","l"]}
```

I tried applying a newline before each key but it only prints this:

```
{"\nstring1":["a","b","c"], "\nstring2":["d","e","f"],"\nstring3":["g","h","i"], 
"\nstring4":["j","k","l"]}
```

This is my function (including the main function):

```
import csv

def read_dictionary():
    with open("text.tsv") as tsvfile:
        tsvreader = csv.reader(tsvfile, delimiter = "\t")
        d = {}
        for line in tsvreader:
            first_row = line[0:1] 
            rest_rows = line[1:]
            for strings in first_row: #converting lists into strings
                d["\n"+strings] = rest_rows
        return d

if __name__=="__main__":
   print(read_dictionary())
```

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to achieve? Do you know about `csv.DictReader` ? Are you sure that you don't want to work with `json` instead of `csv`?

Comment: I wasn't taught anything about csv.DictReader unfortunately.. The task I need to submit also specifies the use of csv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dictionaries (like all built-in containers) are represented with their contents shown as representations, essentially using the [`repr()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) on each. For strings, those are meant to be as helpful as possible in that they are shown as *string literals* that can simply be copied and pasted to recreate their value. That means they also show unprintable characters or characters with special meaning as *escape sequences*. Your newline characters are just such characters.

In other words, you can't do what you want just by inserting `\n` characters in the string values.

Instead, you need to do your *own* formatting if you really want to show your dictionary that way. Just print out the keys and values yourself:

```
def represent_dict(d):
    print('{', end='')  # no newline
    first = True
    for key, value in d.items():
        # newline at the start, not end, with commas
        print('{}\n{!r}: {!r}'.format('' if first else ',', key, value), end='')
        first = False
    print('}')  # closing with a brace and a newline
```

Remove the `\n` addition in your reading code; it can be simplified to just produce the dictionary directly with a dictionary comprehension:

```
def read_dictionary():
    with open("text.tsv") as tsvfile:
        tsvreader = csv.reader(tsvfile, delimiter = "\t")
        return {row[0]: row[1:] for row in tsvreader}

represent_dict(read_dictionary())
```

You generally should keep *presentation* and *data structure* separate. Those newlines in the keys can easily cause issues elsewhere, and they are only there for the presentation output.

Demo of the output:

```
>>> dictionary = {"string1":["a","b","c"], "string2":["d","e","f"],
...               "string3":["g","h","i"], "string4":["j","k","l"]}
>>> represent_dict(dictionary)
{
'string1': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
'string2': ['d', 'e', 'f'],
'string3': ['g', 'h', 'i'],
'string4': ['j', 'k', 'l']}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Gonna try this now.

Answer (score 1):

While a very good answer is given, this would be an alternative method of printing the dictionary, by converting its key/item pairs to a list, same result, just less lines of code, this answer given as alternative:

```
def print_mydict(my_dict):
    my_list = list(my_dict.items())
    print('{')
    for i in my_list[:-1]:
        print('"{}":{},'.format(i[0], i[1]))
    print('"{}":{}}}'.format(my_list[-1][0], my_list[-1][1]))
```

but the last line looks more complex and less "readable", output the same:

```
{
"string1":['a', 'b', 'c'],
"string2":['d', 'e', 'f'],
"string3":['g', 'h', 'i'],
"string4":['j', 'k', 'l']}
```

Comment: That's also very awesome! Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score -1):

You could use template string or multiple print calls to achieve this.